# Listing json class foreach problem in view

Tags: json, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
@foreach (var clubName in item.sport_event.competitors)
{

    string deneme = clubName.name;
    <label>@deneme</label><br />
}

//////  I used labels and br because the values ​​are side by side.
```

My problem the showing team names with using Json data with Newtonsoft.Json deserialize..

This is my competitor class;

```
public class Competitor
    {

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("country")]
        public string country { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("country_code")]
        public string country_code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("abbreviation")]
        public string abbreviation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("qualifier")]
        public string qualifier { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("gender")]
        public string gender { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is sport_event class;

```
 public class SportEvent
    {

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("start_time")]
        public DateTime start_time { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("start_time_confirmed")]
        public bool start_time_confirmed { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sport_event_context")]
        public SportEventContext sport_event_context { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("coverage")]
        public Coverage coverage { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("competitors")]
        public IList<Competitor> competitors { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sport_event_conditions")]
        public SportEventConditions sport_event_conditions { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("venue")]
        public Venue venue { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("channels")]
        public IList<Channel> channels { get; set; }
    }
```

My problem --> How can I bring in team names one by one?
or like real madrid - barcelona ?

Using my foreach code the result is like; Rc Real Madrid Barcelona FC
i want them one by one...

There is my Json example..

```
"competitors": [
                    {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:35179",
                        "name": "Real SC Queluz",
                        "country": "Portugal",
                        "country_code": "PRT",
                        "abbreviation": "REQ",
                        "qualifier": "home",
                        "gender": "male"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:3004",
                        "name": "Belenenses SAD",
                        "country": "Portugal",
                        "country_code": "PRT",
                        "abbreviation": "SAD",
                        "qualifier": "away",
                        "gender": "male"
                    }
                ],
```

Comment: Is my answer helpful?Or I misunderstood what you want.If so,you can tell what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to get teamname1 - teamname2.If so,you can do like this:

```
<label>@item.sport_event.competitors[0].name - @item.sport_event.competitors[1].name</label>
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a collection of Competitor objects.

the code would then look something like this:

```
List<Competitor> competitors = new List<Competitor>();
competitors.Add(new Competitor //code omitted...
```

There are other ways to populate the competitors list.  Now let's assume you have 5 Competitor objects in the list. The next thing you would do is simply iterate over the list.

List implements the IEnumerable interface, so you can just use foreach.

```
   foreach (Competitor competitor in Competitors)
   {

       Console.WriteLine(competitor.name); //name should capitalized to Name as it's a property
   }
```

I see there is already a collection member

```
 [JsonProperty("competitors")]
        public IList<Competitor> competitors { get; set; }
```

So you can just iterate over this collection also using the foreach statement.